# django-filter + DRF ModelViewSet different behaviour for different fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have the following ViewSets (My current code)

```py
class TeacherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['user_id', ]
    search_fields = ['=user_id']


class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = School.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['udise', ]
    search_fields = ['=udise']
```

The models look like this

```py
class Teacher(BaseModel):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField()


class School(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    udise = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

And the serializer for School is as follows

```py
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = '__all__'
        validators = []
```

If I change it to this (which I assume should work like `TeacherSet`

```py
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = School.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['udise', ]
    search_fields = ['=udise']
```

The issue that I am facing is

- `/school/?udise=111` doesn't work and doesn't filter anything
- `/teacher/?user_id=4a031bd9-4c02-4f9a-8c1b-56fb68965021` works perfectly fine.

I think I am missing something really basic here. Both `user_id` and `udise` are unique in the database.
So to mitigate this I am currently using a hack - `search_fields` with and `=` on DRF's default `SearchFilter` backend.

Comment: where are you importing the `SearchFilter` from in `SchoolViewset`? I mean, in the `TeacherViewSet` you are using it directly, whereas in the second viewset you are accessing it via `filters.SearchFilter`

Comment: @Ersain when I replace `filters.SearchFilter` in `SchoolViewSet` with `DjangoFilterBackend` it returns everything under the sun. Not sure why that would be the case. These are my imports
`from rest_framework import filters; from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend`

Answer (score 0):

In `/school/?udise=111` and `/teacher/?user_id=4a031bd9-4c02-4f9a-8c1b-56fb68965021` you are trying to filter, not search.

Search url would be sth like: `/?search=sth`. Then it searches in specified fields in `search_fields`, and tries to find object matching those field. And those fields should be text type for being able to search. See docs about search: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter

But here, you are trying to filter, So you should use `DjangoFilterBackend` or a custom filter for filtering:

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
```

Comment: when I replace `filters.SearchFilter` in SchoolViewSet with `DjangoFilterBackend` it doesn't filter anything.

Comment: Updated for clarity